# 404 Not Found error while when i use ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.2, apache2

I know this thread has been talked a lot on the web and here, and I tried almost all the methods, but still I'm having the same problem.

***My conf file:***

```
<Proxy balancer://balancer-applitutoriel>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8888 route=js1 retry=30 keepalive=on ttl=10 loadfactor=3 flushpackets=auto timeout=300

        Require all granted
</Proxy>

AliasMatch ^/myApp/static-([^/]+)/(.*)$ /var/www/html/myApp/static-$1/$2
ProxyPassMatch ^/myApp/static !
ProxyPass /myApp balancer://balancer-applitutoriel/myApp stickysession=NODESESSIONID nofailover=on

ProxyErrorOverride On
ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.html
```

***In folder `/var/www/html` i have this:***

```
myApp
│   └── static-1.0.0-20170512094719
│       ├── config-spa.json
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── auth.css
│       │   └── theme.css
│       ├── custom_404.html
└── index.html
```

The custom error page is not working. So what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `custom_404.html` is in the wrong directory. It needs to be in `/var/www/html` for that configuration.
You can also leave it where it is, but then it is
`ErrorDocument 404 /myApp/static-1.0.0-20170512094719/custom_404.html`

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/myApp/static-1.0.0-20170512094719/custom_404.html
```

We are providing full path with domain name to error file.